# LINQ expression return null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query in LINQ. "Symbol" doesn't exist, and the query is null, but I got an error, of casting and the program crashes.

```
decimal x = from cie in m_entities.Cie
            where cie.symbol.Equals(Symbol)
            select cie.cie_id;
```

Or can I have a null in x?

Comment: What is the **exact** exception message you get?

Comment: Assuming `m_entities.Cie` is an IQueryable or IEnumerable, how does this program compile to produce an exception at run-time, as the result of the query should be an IEnumerable and not a decimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think x will ever be null -- you'll just get an empty `IQueryable<T>` (or is it `IEnumrable<T>`?), where T is the datatype of `cie_id`.

The casting error is because you're attempting to cast the collection to a `decimal`.

Comment: ...so you can wrap the query in `(...)` and then call `.FirstOrDefault()` to return the lone result or `0`.

Comment: The cast is implicit in that the query returns a collection, but `x` is being declared as a `decimal`. If `x` were declared with `var` there would be no `InvalidCastException`, but `x` would not be a `decimal`, either.

Comment: Shouldn't this produce a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<decimal>' to 'decimal'" error at compile-time?

Comment: Yes, and I assume that it does, but that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that cie_id is a decimal, then try this:

```
decimal x = (from cie in m_entities.Cie
                     where cie.symbol.Equals(Symbol)
                     select cie.cie_id).FirstOrDefault()
```

Your current code tries to assign IEnumerable<decimal> to decimal, which won't work.
FirstOrDefault will select the first match, if any, otherwise 0.

If you know there will be either 1 or 0 matches, you could consider SingleOrDefault instead of FirstOrDefault.